# How to get out of repetitive if statements?

Tags: algorithm, c#-4.0, if-statement

While looking though some code of the project I'm working on, I've come across a pretty hefty method which does 
the following:

```
public string DataField(int id, string fieldName)
{
   var data = _dataRepository.Find(id);
   if (data != null)
  {
      if (data.A == null)
      {
        data.A = fieldName;
        _dataRepository.InsertOrUpdate(data);
        return "A";
      }

      if (data.B == null)
      {
        data.B = fieldName;
        _dataRepository.InsertOrUpdate(data);
        return "B";
      }

    // keep going data.C through data.Z  doing the exact same code
  }
}
```

Obviously having 26 if statements just to determine if a property is null and then to update that property and do a database call is
probably very naive in implementation. What would be a better way of doing this unit of work?

Comment: Introducing: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The root of your problem is the class with 26 properties called A through to Z. Is there a reason it's not an array or dictionary or something?

Comment: What exactly is the application doing.  I am trying to think of things that would require 26 properties of the alphabet, and everything I've come up with so far is just for "Fun".

Comment: This isn't such a far-fetched problem. Imagine a class that has a couple dozen `string` properties, and a command interface that wants to change them. So somebody could type a command like "set name = jim" or "set key = abc123". It's the same type of problem. If you're developing the class at the same time you're developing the command interface, then you can write the class to support it. But if you want to implement the command interface after the class is already in production, you have a very similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully [C# is able to inspect and assign class members dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z80c09w2.aspx), so one option would be to create a <strike>map</strike> list and iterate over that.

```
    public string DataField(int id, string fieldName)
    {
        var data = _dataRepository.Find(id);

        List<string> props = new List<string>();
        props.Add("A");
        props.Add("B");
        props.Add("C");

        if (data != null)
        {
            Type t = typeof(data).GetType();
            foreach (String entry in props) {
                PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(entry);
                if (pi.GetValue(data) == null) {
                    pi.SetValue(data, fieldName);
                    _dataRepository.InsertOrUpdate(data);
                    return entry;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While I wasn't able to directly use your code, the lookup of the PropertyInfo on an object got us to really start thinking of what we're doing. After a little more code review we have actually decided to change our data scheme and attack our problem in a very different way rather than using the setup of "a","b","c"...Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop through all the character from 'A' to 'Z'. It gets difficult because you want to access an attribute of your 'data' object with the corresponding name, but that should (as far as I know) be possible through the C# reflection functionality.

While you get rid of the consecutive if-statements this still won't make your code nice :P

Comment: These are the things that I feared would come when people first told me about reflection... Its like built-in support for bad style :D

Comment: Totally agree, nothing made the code look nice, so we've go ahead and looked a little further back and have decided to make some changes to the underlying data scheme.

Answer (score 1):

there is a fancy linq solution for your problem using reflection:

but as it was said before: your datastructure is not very well thought through

```
public String DataField(int id, string fieldName)
{
    var data = new { Z = "test", B="asd"};
    Type p = data.GetType();

    var value = (from System.Reflection.PropertyInfo fi 
                     in p.GetProperties().OrderBy((fi) => fi.Name)
                     where fi.Name.Length == 1 && fi.GetValue(data, null) != null 
                     select fi.Name).FirstOrDefault();
    return value;
}
```

ta taaaaaaaaa
like that you get the property but the update is not yet done.

Comment: I really liked the linq way of diving into the properties of an object and iterating over the PropertyInfo of each item. I went ahead and tried this, but found out that our requirements were even more screwy than what I thought at face value. Thanks for the insight, and you started a new conversation with us in rethinking our data scheme and the way our classes will work with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Since you always set the lowest alphabet field first and return, you can use an additional field in your class that tracks the first available field. For example, this can be an integer `lowest_alphabet_unset` and you'd update it whenever you set data.{X}:

Init:

```
lowest_alphabet_unset = 0;
```

In DataField:

```
lowest_alphabet_unset ++;
switch (lowest_alphabet_unset) {

    case 1: 
        /* A is free */
        /* do something */
        return 'A';
    [...]

    case 7:
        /* A through F  taken */
        data.G = fieldName;
        _dataRepository.InsertOrUpdate(data);
        return 'G';
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = _dataRepository.Find(id);
```

If possible, you should use another DataType without those 26 properties. That new DataType should have 1 property and the Find method should return an instance of that new DataType; then, you could get rid of the 26 if in a more natural way.

To return "A", "B" ... "Z", you could use this:

```
return (char)65; //In this example this si an "A"
```

And work with some transformation from data.Value to a number between 65 and 90 (A to Z).

Answer (score -1):

**N.B. -- do not use, if data is object rather that structure.**

what comes to my mind is that, if A-Z are all same type, then you could theoretically access memory directly to check for non null values.

```
start = &data;

for (i = 0; i < 26; i++){
   if ((typeof_elem) *(start + sizeof(elem)*i) != null){
      *(start + sizeof(elem)*i) = fieldName;
      return (char) (65 + i);
   }
}
```

not tested but to give an idea ;)

Comment: it is risky, but if all done properly, would work smoothly. although, if data is an object rather than struct, then this would not be a good way to go I must admit.

Comment: Among other things, this assumes that the fields are laid out in-order in the object (or struct). It also requires unsafe code (which you don't show). And, as you say, it's not going to work well if `data` is a reference type (which is likely).

Comment: My answer was rather to point that it's sometimes better to fix the root of the problem rather than to create a solution for it. Namely, the initial structure of the data object(?) should  be revisited. + it was fun to show some insights into low level approach.